# What's the technology used by the tiles at stackoverflow.com's site list?

Tags: discussion, javascript, stack-exchange

I'd like to use the tech for [stackoverflow.com's site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites). The dynamic tile layout is really cool. I wonder how it is built.

After viewing the code, I just find jquery js reference.

Is it built using jquery? If so, what module it uses exactly?

Comment: You mean http://stackexchange.com/sites , right?

Comment: It's the "JQuery Isotope" plugin -- http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: @Ian right dude.

Comment: @McGarnagle exactly what I want. BTW why the downvote? Isn't query for technology allowed here?

Comment: Hey I think there's a debate on whether this thread is welcome here. I'd like to ask you to say whether it is allowed to ask for what technology to use.

Comment: @SolessCHong I'm not sure why someone downvoted, seems like a legit question to me.  I think some people take offense if they think you could have found the answer by yourself with some reseach.

Comment: I heard you were trying to find out what jQuery module they used to build Stack Exchange. You should totally drop that and try jQuery.